# What is the expected ingestion pace for a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I am running a project that requires to load millions of records to cassandra.
I am using kafka connect and doing partitioning and raising 24 workers I only get around 4000 rows per second.
I did a test with pentaho pdi inserting straight to cassandra with jdbc driver and I get a litle bit less rows per second: 3860 (avg)
The cassandra cluster has 24 nodes. What is the expected insertion pace by default? how can i fine tune the ingestion of big loads of data?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is somewhat open ended - no details of what is being inserted, or if you are using LWTs / Batches which would have a large impact. That being said - 4k rows/second for writes is very slow, for a 24 node cluster, its terribly slow. You will need to identify the bottleneck and ask a targeted question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magical "default" rate that a Cassandra cluster can ingest data. One cluster can take 100K ops/sec, another can do 10M ops/sec. In theory, it can be limitless.

A cluster's throughput is determined by a lot of moving parts which include (but NOT limited to):

- hardware configuration
- number of cores, type of CPU
- amount of memory, type of RAM
- disk bandwidth, disk configuration
- network capacity/bandwidth
- data model
- client/driver configuration
- access patterns
- cluster topology
- cluster size

The only way you can determine the throughput of your cluster is by doing your own test on as close to production loads as you can simulate. Cheers!